# What object types that are referenced by file descriptors?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, file-descriptor

I was wondering what object types are implemented as file descriptors in Posix/Unix.

I could not find a list, so I looked at the references in man pages for [close()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) and [select()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) (because those are supposed to operate on all fd types).

The object types I found:

- files
- sockets
- message queues

  ```
   On Linux, a message queue descriptor is actually a file
   descriptor.  (POSIX does not require such an implementation.)
  ```
- pipes
- shared memory

Are there more? Are there fd-versions of pthreads sync objects (semaphore, mutex, cond)? Is there a list?

Comment: It is free for every vendor to use the file interface for whatever it is needed. Linux provides also a timer with file descriptor. The idea is to use it with other IO in event based loops with `select`. Every OS user can write drivers on base of file descriptors as well..

Answer (score 0):

There is no full list of which are using file descriptor, but based on [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor):

> In Unix and Unix-like computer operating systems, a file descriptor (FD, less frequently fildes) is a unique identifier ([handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing))) for a [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) or other input/output resource, such as a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) or [network socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

Thus, it includes all derivatives of [file](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/file-types-linuxunix-explained-detail/), [IPC](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-storage), and [socket](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html). Need to know that pipe is part of IPC and IPCs are utilize file descriptor.